# How read image more than one time using libpng?

Tags: c++, image, png, libpng

Is there any method to refresh `png_ptr` state to begin and i can read png image using `png_read_rows`

Comment: There might be, but *why*? You should be storing the data in memory rather than re-reading it from disk, which is essentially the slowest thing a computer can do.

Comment: I need to read the part of iterlaced image. For example 1/3 of the image. Than i have to read some other part. The task is not to store the whole image, just it parts. That is why i am asking

Comment: Did you look at [reading files progressively](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.10)? It seems to me that  you can use the callback functions with a do-nothing logic for the unwanted rows.

Comment: Callback function will be executed after reading each row. Sorry, do not understand how empty callback func would help me. Explain please